# Add white box around image in PHP ImageMagick extension

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

For years I've been using exec to do my ImageMagick work on PHP.  However, I've now moved to the PHP ImageMagic extension.  However, I'm unable to replicate my command in that.

I want to take an image and resize it and add extra white space around it so it fits within those dimensions.

My original imagemagic exec code is:

```
exec("convert -define jpeg:size=100x100 test.jpg -thumbnail '480x360>' -background white -gravity center -extent  480x360  output.jpg");
```

This works perfectly but I now want to replicate it in ImageMagick PHP extension. I tried the below but it doesn't work.

```
$im = new Imagick('input.jpg');
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->setGravity('Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER');
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('white');
$im->extentImage( 480, 360);

$im->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

I expect the output to be a an image that fits within the box of 480x360 and adds white space around it.  The image will be 100% visible with white space around the area.  So if I uploaded a 100x300 image, it'll be letterbox within a white box.

Answer (score 3):

When working with the API, the `extentImage` requires you to calculate the page (x, y)  offset.

```php
Imagick::extentImage ( int $width , int $height , int $x , int $y ) : bool
```

Setting the gravity has no effect here, and there should be a PHP warning emitted (check logs).

Try the following...

```
$im = new Imagick('rose:');
$im->setImageBackgroundColor('GREEN');
$offsetX = 240 - $im->getImageWidth() / 2;
$offsetY = 180 - $im->getImageHeight() / 2;
$im->extentImage( 480, 360, -$offsetX, -$offsetY);
$im->writeImage('output.jpg');
```

[image: output.jpg]